# Are the maximal noun phrases found by this code incorrect?

Tags: phrases, nouns, noun-phrases

I was reading the accepted answer
[to this question on natural language processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587667/extracting-all-nouns-from-a-text-file-using-nltk)

In there an english sentence is given:

"Natural language processing (NLP) is a field of computer science, artificial intelligence, and computational linguistics concerned with the interactions between computers and human (natural) languages."

Now my grade school understanding of noun phrases suggests that the maximal noun phrases here are:

"Natural language processing (NLP)"

"field of computer science, artificial intelligence, and computational linguistics"

"interactions between computers and human (natural) languages"

But the maximal noun phrases that the code finds are:

"['natural language processing', 'nlp', 'computer science', 'artificial intelligence', 'computational linguistics']"

Is my intuition correct and this computer code is NOT GIVING maximal phrases or do I have an incorrect understanding of noun phrases.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "maximal noun phrase" and when I searched for it on line I only got hits referring to it as a concept in Chinese. Are you a native Chinese speaker? Having said that I would be surprised if the code was working optimally since it is returning NLP as a noun phrase whereas it is an abbreviation of Natural Language Processing in the given text. It is also used as an abbreviation for Neuro Linguistic Programming which is something else entirely.

Comment: No I’m a native English speaker. I guess I just assumed that’s a common term. What is the word for “largest noun phrase that doesn’t run into the verb of the sentence”

Comment: Apologies for my fabrication of terminology.

Comment: I'm not saying that "maximal noun phrase" isn't a linguistic term, just that it's unfamiliar to me and seems to be unknown to Google except in Chinese. Given your definition (which I can understand) I can see how "a field of computer science, artificial intelligence and computational linguistics" could be regarded as a very long, possibly maximal, noun phrase but the problem is that it contains a list of shorter noun phrases. How you get software (even an AI) to recognise such forms reliably is closer to your pay grade than my (former) one!

Comment: You’re more correct than the coded. However there are just 2 maximal NPs here. You identified the first. The second starts with *a field* and goes all the way to the end of the sentence.

Comment: 'Natural language processing' and 'NLP' are in apposition (the special case where an initialism is given after the full name, the offsetting device almost always being brackets). A typical NP cannot be omitted from a sentence without affecting grammaticality unless it is in apposition. Here, either the expanded or the abbreviated form may be dropped, but not both. This argues for 2 NPs.

Comment: Actually, @EdwinAshworth’s right about “Natural ... NLP” containing two distinct maximal NP’s here. So there’s 3 in total. (NLP) here is a supplement.